# Non-inset is showing collapsible-set too wide

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

We are using jquery-mobile..and added a collapsible listview with non-inset="false" so it will fit the whole width of the mobile screen.

Now we have set it, the listview and divider are too wide, so it is not fitting correctly in the screen. If we set inset="true" the lsitview fits correctly into the screen..but we would like to have non-inset..

what could be wrong, do we have to style it custom?

Comment: Got example code or a jsFiddle that explains what you're using?

Comment: I put a new page online, so you could have a look at it.. even without customs.css it won't show correctly..
[link](http://lc.gorillaspots.nl/new/home.php)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do to make it work as intended is to set `data-role="content"` to `div` container of your collapsible.

```
<div data-role="content" class="content-primary">
    <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false">
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pmatseykanets/c3ttz/)